# Having Multiple Values Inside One Array - For Loop?

Tags: php

**The Script:**

```
<?php
        include("connect.php");    
?>    
<form method="POST" action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name1" />
    <input type="text" name="name2" />
    <input type="text" name="name3" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>    
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $name3 = $_POST['name3'];

    $myarray = array($name1, $name2, $name3);   

    for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++){

        $tqs = "SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `image_file` IN ('" . $myarray[$i] . "')";
        $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        $fetch_array = array();
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr);
        $fetch_array[] = $row['id'];

        print_r($fetch_array);    
    }    
}    
?>
```

The script prints:

```
Array ( [0] => 558 ) Array ( [0] => 559 ) Array ( [0] => 560 )
```

How to have these values inside ***one*** array?

E.g.:

```
Array ( [0] => 558 [1] => 559 [2] => 560 )
```

The image file names come from the form and the values come from the ID column of the "images" table. And I am looking to have the selected stored inside ***one*** array.

Comment: take a look at array_puch(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're destroying the array and recreating it on each iteration. Move that line out of the loop, and don't print the array on each iteration:

```
$fetch_array = array(); // only create the array once

for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++){
    $tqs = "SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `image_file` IN ('" . $myarray[$i] . "')";
    $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr);
    $fetch_array[] = $row['id'];
}

print_r($fetch_array); // only output once
```

---

Side note: your query is vulnerable to SQL Injection. Switch to a Prepared Statement with bound parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your array outside the loop. Otherwise you keep overwriting the array.

```
<?php
    include("connect.php");
?>

<form method="POST" action="<?PHP echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name1" />
    <input type="text" name="name2" />
    <input type="text" name="name3" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $name3 = $_POST['name3'];

    $myarray = array($name1, $name2, $name3);

    $fetch_array = array();     // <----------- Declare here
    for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++){

        $tqs = "SELECT `id` FROM `images` WHERE `image_file` IN ('" . $myarray[$i] . "')";
        $tqr = mysqli_query($dbc, $tqs) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($tqr);
        $fetch_array[] = $row['id'];
    }

    print_r($fetch_array);      // <----------- Print here
}

?>
```